# Jquery.Ajax function not getting a file in the base directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So I'm trying to use Ajax to pull a json file from the base directory and it seems to always return with an error. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    GetTrivia();
});

/*==Functions==*/
function GetTrivia() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../json/Questions.json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("It didn't work");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Antiga Ah yeah I figured it was probably something to do with that. I've never used JSON from a local file, only ever gotten it dynamically from an api. Thanks

Comment: 1. Make sure that your path is relative to the location of the JS file.
2. Pulling JSON locally never seems to work for me unless I include the dataType property.

Comment: @DannyGibas This fixed it! Thank you.